# How Do You Draw Concentric Squares?

Tags: processing

-Create a sketch of 10 concentric squares of different colors
-Incorporate user input when the mouse or keyboard is pressed changed the colors of the squares
-Code must use variables/ loops/ and decision structures.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is having them be concentric, use [rectMode()](https://processing.org/reference/rectMode_.html)

```
rectMode(CENTER);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  rect(width / 2, height / 2, 10 * (i + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The term concentric, while usually used for circles, is actually just based on the Latin for "same centre". Hence concentric squares are just those that have the same center (where the diaganols meet).

So, let's say you need the upper left corner (where `X` increases across to the right, `Y` increases down to the bottom) and side length. To work out the center of an existing square:

```
centX = X + length / 2
centY = Y + length / 2
```

Then to work out the upper left co-ordinates for a new square of given length (that's concentric with the first):

```
X = centX - length / 2
Y = centY - length / 2
```

You can wrap that up in a function (pseudo-code) with somwething like:

```
def makeConcentricSquare(origX, origY, origLen, newLen):
    newX = origX + origLen / 2 - newLen / 2
    newY = origY + origLen / 2 - newLen / 2
    return (newX, newY, newLen)
```

---

This is, of course, assuming your squares are horizontal in nature. You can do similar things to rotate them but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader, especially since the specifications make no mention of allowing for it :-)